# Get cross origin resource in nodejs from php

Tags: php, node.js

Suppose there are two servers serv1 & serv2. i am trying to get xmlhttprequest from a php in serv1 in a node server in serv2. My code looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'serv1');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
app.use(cors());
app.get('/session', function(req, res) {
    var u = "serv2/somephp.php";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", u, true);
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.onload = function() {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.send();
})
app.listen(8165, function() {
    console.log('Express File Uploading server listening on port 8165');
})
```

Comment: Cors origin settings need to be implemented on php as it is serving request from nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest doesn't exist in node.
Just do a simple http get request with request module :

```
var request = require("request");
request.get({url: "https://www.example.com/a"},function(err, response, body){

});
```

In addition, domain must be defined in your url:

```
 var u = "serv2/somephp.php";
```

CORS rules must be set on the target server (php server)